# NSnotificationCenter postNotificationName who is the receiver?

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, receiver

The documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html talks of the sender and notification name but where does it mention whom to post this notification to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't post a notification directly to someone. The name of the notification, and sender determine who gets the notification.

Interested objects can subscribe to a notification. When you post a notification, all subscribers who are listening to a notification by that name will get notified. Actually Cocoa notifications can be tweaked at two levels:

- notification name (string)
- sender

The [class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) illustrates this clearly.

Here's a little ASCII table from the docs showing who gets notified depending on what notification name and sender were used when created:

```
Notification name | Notification sender | Notification set specified
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Specified         | Specified           | Notifications with a particular name from a specific sender.
Specified         | Unspecified         | Notifications with a particular name by any sender.
Unspecified       | Specified           | Notifications posted by a specific sender.
Unspecified       | Unspecified         | All notifications.
```

*Unspecified means a nil value was supplied for that field.*

Notifications allows for a loosely coupled design as objects are not tied together in their implementations and can work independently off each other.

Comment: Could you please elucidate "Notifications allows for a loosely coupled design as objects are not tied together in their implementations and can work independently off each other."

Comment: Also, in addObserver:selector:name:object: I didn't understand the selector parameter. Please explain.

Comment: Let's say there are two classes `A` and `B` and whenever some event happens, an object of `A` needs to notify an object of `B`. Without notifications, we can directly call some method of `B` directly from some method of `A` thus tying both classes together and creating a hard dependency. With notifications, `A` can just broadcast that the event happened to the notification manager, and if `B` is *listening*, then it will notified of the event. If not, then the event just goes unnoticed. But we didn't tie both classes together in this case.

Comment: The `selector` parameter is the method in the observer object that should be called when that notification is posted by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

`notification` is a *broadcasting* mechanism. As from the doc, "Objects register with a notification center to receive notifications (NSNotification objects) using the addObserver:selector:name:object: or addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: methods." i.e., any object interested can register as a *listener*.

Comment: where should I add this NSnotificaton statement in my code? Should I put it in the function that must be the listener?

Comment: @Namratha I suggest you refer to the MoviePlayer sample http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798 for reference.